# Possible to detect cursors (nested cursors) within T-SQL code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm hoping to find a way to sniff out potentially inefficient T-SQL within stored procedures, in this case detecting not just cursors in stored procedures, but preferably *nested cursors*.

With the script below based on sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities, from a given starting stored procedure I can see a recursive downstream call stack, including a column indicating whether the text CURSOR was found within the procedure definition.

This is helpful, but it isn't capable of telling me:

1. whether more than one cursor exists within a procedure
2. whether *nested* cursors are used (and of course, the truly perfect    solution for that would also have to detect a call to stored procedure containing a cursor, from within a cursor)

Being able to do this I think is probably beyond the abilities of querying sys tables, and involves parsing the SQL itself - does anyone know of a technique or tool that could accomplish this, or perhaps an entirely different approach that could tell me the same information.

```
DECLARE @procname varchar(30)
SET @procname='dbo.some_root_procedure_name'
;WITH CTE([DB],[OBJ],[INDENTED_OBJ],[SCH],[lvl],[indexof_cursor],[referenced_object_definition])
AS
(
    SELECT referenced_database_name AS [DB],referenced_entity_name AS [OBJ],
    cast(space(0) + referenced_entity_name as varchar(max)) AS [INDENTED_OBJ],
    referenced_schema_name AS [SCH],0 AS [lvl]
    ,charindex('cursor',object_definition(referenced_id)) as indexof_cursor
    ,object_definition(referenced_id) as [referenced_object_definition]
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(@procname, 'OBJECT') 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects as o on o.object_id=OBJECT_ID(referenced_entity_name)
    WHERE o.type IN ('P','FN','IF','TF') 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT referenced_database_name AS [DB],referenced_entity_name AS [OBJ],
    cast(space(([lvl]+1)*2) + referenced_entity_name as varchar(max)) AS [INDENTED_OBJ],
    referenced_schema_name AS [SCH],[lvl]+1 as [lvl]
    ,charindex('cursor',object_definition(referenced_id)) as indexof_cursor
    ,object_definition(referenced_id) as [referenced_object_definition]
    FROM CTE as c CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(c.SCH+'.'+c.OBJ, 'OBJECT') as ref
    INNER JOIN sys.objects as o on o.object_id=OBJECT_ID(referenced_entity_name)
    WHERE o.type IN ('P','FN','IF','TF') and ref.referenced_entity_name NOT IN (c.OBJ)  -- Exit Condition
) 
SELECT 
* 
FROM CTE
```

EDIT: I am marking this as "solved" even though I think some improvements could be made to the below solution - I think it is "good enough" for most scenarios, but I think a fully recursive solution that can traverse an "infinitely" deep call chain is possible.

Comment: Have you checked what a nested cursor's execution plan looks like? Alternatively, don't even bother tracking down the nested cursors; simply track down the non-performant procedures and cached execution plans. You will get better bang for you buck, because you will not be distracted by inefficient procedures that don't access enough data to be a true problem.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, but I'm looking for *potentials* for current or future risk.  Or another way of putting it: if I had this query in my toolkit, would I run it , regardless of any current performance issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a more efficient way, but you could search the procedure code.  It's not foolproof though in that it could get some false positives, but you shouldn't miss any.  It doesn't ignore comments and variable names so it's quite possible to pick up some extra stuff.

```
SELECT name, xtype, colid, text
into #CodeBlocks
FROM dbo.sysobjects left join .dbo.syscomments 
ON dbo.sysobjects.id = .dbo.syscomments.id
where xtype = 'P'
order by 1

SELECT name,
        (SELECT convert(varchar(max),text)  
        FROM #CodeBlocks t2
        WHERE t1.name = t2.name  
        ORDER BY t2.colid
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) text
into #AllCode
FROM #CodeBlocks t1
GROUP BY name

select #AllCode.name,
    case when InterProc.name is not null then
        'Possible Inter-Proc Nesting'
    when #AllCode.text like '%CURSOR%FOR%CURSOR%FOR%DEALLOCATE%DEALLOCATE%' then
        'Possible Nested Cursor'
    when #AllCode.text like '%CURSOR%FOR%CURSOR%FOR%' then
        'Possible Multiple Cursor Used'
    ELSE
        'Possible Cursor Used'
    end
from #AllCode
left join #AllCode InterProc
on InterProc.text like '%CURSOR%FOR%'
    and #AllCode.text like '%CURSOR%FOR%' + InterProc.name + '%DEALLOCATE%'
where #AllCode.text like '%CURSOR%FOR%'
```

I found a few nested cursors on our server I didn't know about.  Interesting. :)

Comment: This is actually very clever!  It doesn't catch inter-procedure nested cursors, but I wonder if somehow combining a cross apply concatenation of my above query with this might somehow pull that off.

Comment: For future reference (needs recursive CTE though):  http://www.developwithpurpose.com/concatenate-child-column-values-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for the article... That's nice way to do it!  I didn't think about inter-procedure nesting.... wow.  I suppose you could do a self join to find references.  Would only find inter-procedure nesting one level deep, but you could expand on it to do a recursive search for deeper nesting.  Added to answer.

Comment: My above comment is incorrect - instead, what I think needs to be done is within the SP text, *replace* dbo.SomeProcName with the *definition* of that proc, and if you recurse this process, you'll end up with the entire "procedure call chain" all in one statement, and *then* use the logic in your case statements on that, and you'll have achieved full inter-process nesting detection.  At least I think so.  If so, I have an unrelated but functionally useful query at work I'll have to look at.  This is already pretty great as is, but if the full call stack could be processed, it would be amazing.

Comment: That's a good idea!  You'd just have to program in some loop detection to handle any cases of recursive procedures.  Seems like it wouldn't be to difficult to parse out all the comments before hand as well to eliminate a majority of the false negatives.

Comment: Yes, good point.  How to remove comments...detect (leading '--' + trailing linefeed) or (leading /* + trailing */)?

Comment: NEAR might be useful for the '%CURSOR%FOR%'  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568.aspx